# Flutter Blob to Image

Tags: flutter, base64, flutter-layout, blob, flutter-image

I have to fetch the image from a private server and have to display it. I am using the flutter `Dio` library for API Integrations.

here I I  call to API:

```
Future<GetFileResponse> getFileRequest(GetFileRequest getFileRequest) async {
    try {
      final response = await apiHelper.get(
        "file/${getFileRequest.fileName}",
        headers: {},
      );
      return GetFileResponse(response: response);
    } on Exception catch (ex) {
      throw ex;
    }
  }
```

Here `GetFileResponse.response` type is `var`

Then I have a response like this:

```
�PNG\r\n\u001a\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u00048\u0000\u0000\u00048\b\u0006\u0000\u0000\u0000�\u0010l�\u0000\u0000 \u0000IDATx\u0001��r%���Yd�t���s\u001d��1�'��s5[�\"�?�p\u0000�k��ջ[Rk��L\u0000\u0011\u001e\u001e�\u0000�k�/����?߿��\u001f�^��H�����ߌ(��`_\u0005��}j쳡{�-esЃ�p�v\f23J�� ..Continue...
```

Response:
[API Response on Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvBHU.jpg)

In my Screen I use this Logic to show Image:

```
var pictureBlob = state.getFileResponseEntity.response;
var image = base64.decode(pictureBlob);

CircleAvatar(
 child:Image.memory(image),
),
```

But it executes an error when decoding this. It occurs this error:-

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid character (at character 1)
```

How can I solve this problem?